# Is type.isSubclassOf(Type otherType) cached or do I have to do that myself?

Tags: c#, dictionary, caching, type-conversion, subclass

simple Question:

is type.isSubclassOf(Type otherType) somewhere cached as a let's say `Dictionary<Tuple<Type, Type>, bool>`?

If not, how expensive is such a call?

I'm quite often checking for that to keep my code extendable and am converting methods I use the most into dictionaries...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While it's not ideal do depend on implementation details, we can take a look at the code of `IsSubclassOf` using `dnSpy`

```
public virtual bool IsSubclassOf(Type c)
{
    Type type = this;
    if (type == c)
    {
        return false;
    }
    while (type != null)
    {
        if (type == c)
        {
            return true;
        }
        type = type.BaseType;
    }
    return false;
}
```

So the short answer is that in this version of the framework (`4.6`) the call is not cached, and it implies walking up the inheritance hierarchy.

The question of how expensive the call is depends on your use case. You should measure whether your code spends a significant amount of time in this method and whether a cache helps.

**Performance**

The question of whether it is worth caching the result, is one of measuring the amount of time the call takes vs a cache lookup. I tested 5 scenarios:

1. Direct invocation
2. Cache using: `Dictionary<Tuple<Type, Type>, bool>`
3. Cache using: `Dictionary<(Type, Type), bool>`(value tuple)
4. Cache using: `ConcurrentDictionary<Tuple<Type, Type>, bool>`
5. Cache using: `ConcurrentDictionary<(Type, Type), bool>` (value tuple)

***Results***

1. Direct invocation - 0.15s/ call
2. Cache using: `Dictionary<Tuple<Type, Type>, bool>` - 0.12s / call
3. Cache using: `Dictionary<(Type, Type), bool>` - 0.06s / call
4. Cache using: `ConcurrentDictionary<Tuple<Type, Type>, bool>` - 0.13s/call
5. Cache using: `ConcurrentDictionary<(Type, Type), bool>` (value tuple) - 0.7s/call

`ConcurrentDictionary` with value tuples offers the best thread safe performance, if you don't plan to use the code from multiple threads a simple `Dictionary` with value tuples also works very well.

Generally the cache only halves the call time and the test was not performed for large amount of data in the cache so performance may degrade with more classes. I don't think it's worth caching the result.

***Code***

```
Dictionary<Tuple<Type, Type>, bool> cache = new Dictionary<Tuple<Type, Type>, bool>();
Dictionary<(Type, Type), bool> cache4 = new Dictionary<(Type, Type), bool>();
ConcurrentDictionary<Tuple<Type, Type>, bool> cache2 = new ConcurrentDictionary<Tuple<Type, Type>, bool>();
ConcurrentDictionary<(Type, Type), bool> cache3 = new ConcurrentDictionary<(Type, Type), bool>();
var p = new Dictionary<string, Action>()
{
    { "no chache", ()=> typeof(F).IsSubclassOf(typeof(A)) },
    {
        "dic cache", ()=>
        {
            var key = Tuple.Create(typeof(F),typeof(A));
            if(!cache.TryGetValue(key, out var value))
            {
                cache.Add(key, typeof(F).IsSubclassOf(typeof(A)));
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "vtuple + dic cache", ()=>
        {
            var key = (typeof(F),typeof(A));
            if(!cache4.TryGetValue(key, out var value))
            {
                cache4.Add(key, typeof(F).IsSubclassOf(typeof(A)));
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "concurrent dic cache", ()=>
        {
            cache2.GetOrAdd(Tuple.Create(typeof(F),typeof(A)), (k)=> typeof(F).IsSubclassOf(typeof(A)));
        }
    },
    {
        "vtuple + concurrent + dic cache", ()=>
        {
            cache3.GetOrAdd((typeof(F),typeof(A)), (k)=> typeof(F).IsSubclassOf(typeof(A)));
        }
    },
};
```

Comment: But the question still remains... how expensive is it? Is `==` or `BaseType` expensive? The code you posted could be extremely inexpensive or the opposite.

Comment: @InBetween: Since `==` just uses `Object.ReferenceEquals` the check is pretty cheap: code: `public static bool operator ==(RuntimeType left, RuntimeType right)
        {
            return object.ReferenceEquals(left, right);
        }`

Comment: @TimSchmelter I thought it would be reference equals, but apparently `==` is overloaded for `Type` and is externally implemented .. so it's not straight up `Object.RefernceEquals` (`public static extern bool operator ==(Type left, Type right);`)

Comment: @TimSchmelter yeah I know, which means type objects are already cached somewhere. The point of my comment is that providing the code itself doesn’t really answer the question wether it’s worth caching or not.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir: it is overloaded in a way that it uses `ReferenceEquals` (see my last comment)

Comment: whether != weather

Comment: If you do `typeof(Something).GetType()` you will see that real type is `RuntimeType` (`Type` is abstract). And this `RuntimeType` overrides `IsSubclassOf` so executing code is not exactly what you have shown in answer.

Comment: @Evk you are right, I just checked the code for `RuntimeType` and it's not significantly different.

Comment: @InBetween added some perf tests to measure the differences between caching and non caching versions.

Answer (score 3):

It will not automatically be cached. You will have to weigh the expense of the call vs the memory required to cache. I expect caching in a dictionary will improve performance if there are going to be many such checks.

Answer (score 2):

It seems all the other answers are being a tad too nearsighted. Types are infact cached by the runtime, but no at `Type.BaseType` level.

In cases like these, its actually pretty easy to figure out if there is any caching going on.

Consider the following code and try to guess what the output will be before actually running it:

```
public static void ToCacheOrNotToCache()
{
    var typeofA = typeof(A);
    var typeofB = typeof(B);
    var getTypeA = new A().GetType();
    var getTypeA2 = new A().GetType();
    var getTypeB = new B().GetType();
    var baseTypeB = getTypeB.BaseType;

    Console.WriteLine(
        $"typeof A ref equals getTypeA: {ReferenceEquals(typeofA, getTypeA)}");
    Console.WriteLine(
        $"typeof B ref equals getTypeB: {ReferenceEquals(typeofB, getTypeB)}");
    Console.WriteLine(
        $"typeof A ref equals baseTypeB: {ReferenceEquals(typeofA, baseTypeB)}");
    Console.WriteLine(
        $"getTypeA ref equals getTypeA2: {ReferenceEquals(getTypeA, getTypeA2)}");
}

class A { }
class B: A { }
```

Of course, a closer inspection of the implementation of `Type.BaseType` should have given enough clues to assume some caching is going on at some level; `==(Type, Type)` is the give away; `Type` has no value semantics so if reference equality is used it must mean that one single instance of Type is being used for each type.

The output of the code is of course:

```
typeof A ref equals getTypeA: True
typeof B ref equals getTypeB: True
typeof A ref equals baseTypeB: True
getTypeA ref equals getTypeA2: True
```